# efficient function to find harmonic mean across different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have several dataframes with identical shape/types, but slightly different numeric values.  I can easily produce a new dataframe with the mean of all input dataframes via:

```
df = pd.concat([input_dataframes])
df = df.groupby(df.index).mean()
```

I want to do the same with harmonic mean (probably the scipy.stats.hmean function).  I have attempted to do this using:

```
.groupby(df.index).apply(scipy.stats.hmean)
```

But this alters the structure of the dataframe.  Is there a better way to do this, or do I need to use a more lengthly/manual implementation?

To illustrate :

```
df_input1:
   'a' 'b' 'c'
'x' 1   1   2 
'y' 2   2   4 
'z' 3   3   6

df_input2:
   'a' 'b' 'c'
'x' 2   2   4 
'y' 3   3   6 
'z' 4   4   8

desired output (but w/ hmean):
   'a'  'b'  'c'
'x' 1.5  1.5  3 
'y' 2.5  2.5  5 
'z' 3.5  3.5  7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a pandas Panel, and apply the harmonic mean function over the 'item' axis.

Example with your dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

d = {'1':df1,'2':df2}
pan = pd.Panel(d)
pan.apply(axis='items',func=stats.hmean)
```

yields:

```
        'a'         'b'         'c'
'x'     1.333333    1.333333    2.666667
'y'     2.400000    2.400000    4.800000
'z'     3.428571    3.428571    6.857143
```

Comment: If that helped you, it seems [it is not in bad taste](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer/88539#88539) to ask you to accept it as the answer. It also helps other people find this afterwards, as they'll be able to see your problem was solved without having to read.

Comment: 2024 update:  `pandas.Panel` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Panel.html) `pandas.MultiIndex` is most likely the better choice today.