# How to find the elementwise harmonic mean across two Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy.stats

Simlarly to this post: [efficient function to find harmonic mean across different pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281575/efficient-function-to-find-harmonic-mean-across-different-pandas-dataframes/39281843) I have two Pandas dataframes that are identical in shape and I want to find the harmonic mean of each pair of elements - one from each dataframe in the same location. The solution given in that post was to use a Panel, but that is now deprecated.

If I do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.mstats import hmean

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randint(5, 10, 5), y=np.random.randint(1, 6, 5)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randint(5, 10, 5), y=np.random.randint(1, 6, 5)))
dfs_dictionary = {'DF1':df1,'DF2':df2}
df=pd.concat(dfs_dictionary)
print(df)

       x  y
DF1 0  9  4
    1  6  4
    2  7  2
    3  5  2
    4  5  2
DF2 0  9  2
    1  7  1
    2  7  1
    3  9  5
    4  8  3

x = df.groupby(level = 1).apply(hmean, axis = None).reset_index()
print(x)
   index         0
0      0  4.114286
1      1  2.564885
2      2  2.240000
3      3  3.956044
4      4  3.453237
```

I only get one column of values. Why? I was expecting two columns as per the original df, one for the hmean of the x values and one for the hmean of the y values. How can I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you pass `axis=None` to `hmean`, which flattens the data. Remember when you do `groupby().apply()`, the argument is the whole group, e.g. `df.loc['DF1']`. Just remove `axis=None`:

```
x = df.groupby(level = 1).apply(hmean).reset_index()
```

And you get:

```
   index                                        0
0      0                 [6.461538461538462, 3.0]
1      1  [5.833333333333333, 2.4000000000000004]
2      2                               [8.0, 3.0]
3      3  [6.857142857142858, 2.4000000000000004]
4      4   [6.461538461538462, 2.857142857142857]
```

Or you can use `agg`:

```
x = df.groupby(level = 1).agg({'x':hmean,'y':hmean})
```

and get:

```
          x         y
0  6.461538  3.000000
1  5.833333  2.400000
2  8.000000  3.000000
3  6.857143  2.400000
4  6.461538  2.857143
```

---

In the case you have more columns than just `x,y`:

```
x = df.groupby(level=1).agg({c:hmean for c in df.columns})
```

Comment: There isnt a vectorizes version for that?

Comment: It is vectorized.

Comment: Even the aply version?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove `axis = None` parameter.